# PostsController for href attribute

Tags: haskell, blaze-html, ihp

The following:

```
instance View EditView where
    html EditView { .. } = [hsx|
        <nav>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href={PostsAction}>Posts</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Edit Post</li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
        <h1>Edit Post</h1>
        {renderForm post}
    |]
```

is from the code for the Blog project in the [Creating Your First Project](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/your-first-project.html) section of the IHP guide.

I've mostly converted it from HSX to blaze-html here:

```
instance View EditView where
    html EditView { .. } = do
        H.nav $ do
            H.ol ! A.class_ "breadcrumb" $ do
                H.li ! A.class_ "breadcrumb-item" $ do
                    H.a ! A.href "PostsAction" $ do
                        "Posts"
                H.li ! A.class_ "breadcrumb-item active" $ do
                    "Edit Post"
        H.h1 "Edit Post"
        renderForm post
```

The last bit I'm wondering about is this one:

```
<a href={PostsAction}>Posts</a>
```

If I do the following:

```
H.a ! A.href PostsAction $ do
    "Posts"
```

I get this message:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘H.AttributeValue’
              with actual type ‘PostsController’
• In the first argument of ‘A.href’, namely ‘PostsAction’
  In the second argument of ‘(!)’, namely ‘A.href PostsAction’
  In the expression: H.a ! A.href PostsActiontypecheck
PostsAction
Defined at /home/dharmatech/Dropbox/Documents/ihp-blog/blog/Web/Types.hs:13:7
```

What's a good way to pass `PostsAction` to `A.href`?

(If there are other ways to make the blaze-html expression more idiomatic, feel free to recommend as well. :-))

## Update 1

When I use the following, along the lines of what Willem suggested in his answer below:

```
instance View EditView where
    html EditView { .. } = do
        H.nav $ do
            H.ol ! A.class_ "breadcrumb" $ do
                H.li ! A.class_ "breadcrumb-item" $ do
                    H.a ! A.href (fromString (show PostsAction)) $ do
                        "Posts"
                H.li ! A.class_ "breadcrumb-item active" $ do
                    "Edit Post"
        H.h1 "Edit Post"
        renderForm post
```

I get the following:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘[Char]’
  Expected type: String
    Actual type: Text
• In the first argument of ‘fromString’, namely
    ‘(show PostsAction)’
  In the first argument of ‘A.href’, namely
    ‘(fromString (show PostsAction))’
  In the second argument of ‘(!)’, namely
    ‘A.href (fromString (show PostsAction))’typecheck
```

Perhaps I need to import a `Text` version of `fromString`?

## Update 2

I've added the following import:

```
import Data.String(IsString(fromString))
```

However, the error message is the same:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘[Char]’
  Expected type: String
    Actual type: Text
• In the first argument of ‘fromString’, namely
    ‘(show PostsAction)’
  In the first argument of ‘A.href’, namely
    ‘(fromString (show PostsAction))’
  In the second argument of ‘(!)’, namely
    ‘A.href (fromString (show PostsAction))’typecheck
```

## Update 3

If I hover over `show` the following signature is shown:

```
show :: forall a. Show a => a -> Text
```

And for `fromString`:

```
fromString :: forall a. IsString a => String -> a
```

So I believe that's where the mismatch is.

## Update 4

This being a typical IHP view file, I have the following at the top for imports:

```
module Web.View.Posts.Edit where
import Web.View.Prelude

import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5.Attributes as A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation on *Inline Haskell*](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/hsx.html#inline-haskell) says:

> If the variable is another HSX expression, a blaze HTML element, a text or string: it is just included as you would expect.
>
> If the variable is any other custom Haskell data structure: it will **first be converted to a string representation by calling `show` on it**. You can add a custom `ToHtml` (import it from `IHP.HSX.ToHtml`) instance, to customize rendering a data structure.

So unless there was a `ToHTML` in the `[hsx|…]` quasiquoter for `{PostAction}`, you thus should apply `show`, next we call [**`fromString :: IsString a => String -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-markup-0.8.2.3/docs/Text-Blaze-Internal.html#v:fromString) to it to convert it to an `AttributeValue`.

The code is thus equivalent to:

```
instance View EditView where
    html EditView { .. } = do
        H.nav $ do
            H.ol ! A.class_ "breadcrumb" $ do
                H.li ! A.class_ "breadcrumb-item" $ do
                    H.a ! A.href (fromString (show PostsAction)) $ do
                        "Posts"
                H.li ! A.class_ "breadcrumb-item active" $ do
                    "Edit Post"
        H.h1 "Edit Post"
        renderForm post
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you Willem. Bought you a coffee https://www.buymeacoffee.com/hapytex/c/1885085. 

Comment: Willem, when I use what you suggested above, I get an error regarding `fromString`. I've updated the question with the details. Perhaps I need to import something?

Comment: @dharmatech: did you import `fromString` from the `IsString` typeclass? so `import Data.String(IsString(fromString))`?

Comment: Willem, OK I've added that import to my file. However, I'm getting the same error message. (See `Update 2` on the question above.)

Comment: Willem, see `Update 3` as well. I show there where it seems the type mismatch is.

Comment: @dharmatech: ah but you use a `show` that produces a `Text` whereas it should be the [**`show :: Show a => a -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:show) from the prelude.

Comment: Willem, well, I'm using IHP which it appears sets things up so that `show` produces `Text`. See `Update 4` above for details about my imports. Do you have a suggestion for a way to use the prelude version of show for just this one expression?

Comment: @dharmatech: you can `import Prelude as P` and then work with `P.show`.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you for your help and patience, Willem. Another coffee has been sent your way. :-)